# Вид связи между местоимением и числительным

Tags: грамматика

Их было трое. Их было три человека.

Предложения двусоставные, было ― сказуемое, три человека/трое ― подлежащее.

А местоимение *их* ― его надо включать в состав подлежащего? И  какое слово задает местоимению родительный  падеж?

Answer (score 2):

В школьной грамматике такие предложения - безличные.

Их было трое. Было трое - составное именное сказуемое,  было - связка. Их - дополнение.

Их было три человека. Было три человека - сказуемое, их - дополнение.

В вузовской практике разные мнения, у каждого учёного своё видение.Там такие предложения называются квантитативными — это предложения о количестве: Их было пятеро; Малины в этом лесу мало; Грибов в этом году было много; Кустарнику нет конца (И. Т.); Врагов было много (Аст.).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Меня прежде всего интересовали числительные. 1) Грамматический разбор всё-таки не очень ясен. Например: Их было трое - это безличное предложение. Мальчиков было мало.  В нашей группе их было  (трое) три мальчика. Это предложение тоже безличное или двусоставное?    2) И какая связь: было их или их трое? По смыслу местоимение вроде бы относится к числительному. Но существует ли грамматическая связь "местоимение-числительное"? Например: Остались только мы трое.